# Is there a list of things that have been put away until "l'atid lavo"?

Tags: midrash, latid-lavo-future

There are many mamarei chazal that discuss things that at one point existed and were hidden or saved for "l'atid lavo" (ex the ohr haganuz) does an extensive list of such things exist?

Comment: Drat. When I read the title I thought it'd be about things found with a _siman_. `:-)` +1, though.

Answer (score 2):

The Leviyatan and the Shor HaBor - Babylonian Talmud, Baba Batra 74b

Comment: The Chilazon according to the Arizal was nignaz

Comment: Perhaps we should make a community wiki post and build a list ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

- The Leviathan -  Babylonian Talmud, Baba Batra 74b
- The Shor HaBor - Babylonian Talmud, Baba Batra 74b
- The Light from the first day of creation. Rashi.
- The Chilazon according to the Arizal <sup>source?</sup>
- The bottle of the manna - Horios 12a, Yoma 52b
- The Aaron with the tablets - Mishna Shekalim 6:1-2, Horios 12a, but see Yoma 53b
- The anointing oil - Horios 12a, Yoma 52b
- Aaron's rod - Rashi  Horios 12a, Yoma 52b
- Eliyahu Hanavi - Malbim Melachim II 2:16
- Techeiles - Midrash Raba Bemidbar 17:5
- The Book of Healing - Shabbat 13b
- The Tachas (animal) - Shabbat 28b
- Jerusalem cinnamon  - Shabbat 63a
- The Aaron with gifts that the Pelishtim sent back - Yoma 52b
- The Mishkan - Sota 9a
- Some Para Aduma ashes? <sup>source?</sup>